# C++ struct polymorphism in Arduino

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, polymorphism

I have a class called `Quadruped_Robot` that has four structures, `fRight`, `fLeft`, `bRight`, and `bLeft` that inherit from a base structure, `Leg`. In *Arduino*, I am trying to actuate 8 servo motors by cycling through each one, and the four structures hold the servo driver channel value. I've created an array of pointers to the four structures, so that the function, `actuateLeg`, can send PWM signals to the appropriate channel determined during runtime. However, none of the servos respond, and upon inspecting the values given by `myLeg->channels[0]` and `myLeg->channels[1]`, they report values that are in the range of thousands, both positive and negative. However, the values should be between `0` and `7`. Why are the channel values incorrect when I try to access them using the `->` operator?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

//default address
Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

class Quadruped_Robot{

  private:
  //minimum and maximum pulse length count
  //valid range: [0,4096]
  //0   degrees:    200
  //60  degrees:    360
  //90  degrees:    510
  //180 degrees:    915
  size_t SERVOMIN= 200;
  size_t SERVOMAX= 915;

  //phase shift between upper and lower leg actuation in milliseconds
  size_t OFFSET= 1000;

  //pulse length to servo motors
  size_t PULSE_LENGTH= 100;

  struct Leg{
    int channels[2];
    bool started;
    virtual void foo()=0;
  };

  struct fRight:Leg{
    //channel numbers on the PWM/Servo driver for the front right leg
    //0= upper leg
    //1= lower leg
    int channels[2]= {0, 1};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  };

  struct fLeft:Leg{
    //channel numbers on the PWM/Servo driver for the front left leg
    //2= upper leg
    //3= lower leg
    int channels[2]= {2, 3};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  };

  struct bRight:Leg{
    //channel numbers on the PWM/Servo driver for the back right leg
    //4= upper leg
    //5= lower leg
    int channels[2]= {4, 5};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  };

  struct bLeft:Leg{
    //channel numbers on the PWM/Servo driver for the back left leg
    //6= upper leg
    //7= lower leg
    int channels[2]= {6, 7};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  };

  //bool value indicating whether the servos have begun moving
  bool started= false;

  //holds the previous timestamp
  unsigned long prevTime;

  public:

  Leg* myLegs[4]= {new fRight, new fLeft, new bRight, new bLeft};

  void actuateLeg(size_t leg){  
    prevTime= millis();
    Leg *myLeg= myLegs[leg];
    size_t PWM= SERVOMIN;

    //Actuate upper leg and wait until the phase shift time has elapsed to actuate the lower leg
    while(millis()-prevTime < OFFSET){
      pwm.setPWM(myLeg->channels[0], 0, PWM );
      Serial.println(myLeg->channels[0]);
    }
    prevTime= millis();

    //Actuate lower leg and wait until the phase shift time has elapsed to actuate the upper leg again
    while(millis()-prevTime < OFFSET){
      pwm.setPWM(myLeg->channels[1], 0, PWM );
      Serial.println(myLeg->channels[1]);
    }
    prevTime= millis();
    PWM= SERVOMAX;

    //Actuate upper leg and wait until the phase shift time has elapsed to actuate the lower leg again
    while(millis()-prevTime < OFFSET){
      pwm.setPWM(myLeg->channels[0], 0, PWM );
      Serial.println(myLeg->channels[0]);
    }
    prevTime= millis();

    while(millis()-prevTime < OFFSET){
      pwm.setPWM(myLeg->channels[1], 0, PWM );
      Serial.println(myLeg->channels[1]);
    }
    delete myLeg;
  }

  void walk(){
    actuateLeg(0);
    actuateLeg(2);
    actuateLeg(1);
    actuateLeg(3);
  }

};

//Create a Quadruped_Robot object
Quadruped_Robot myQuadruped;

void setup() {
  //Begin serial communication at 9600 bps
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //MG996R servo runs at 50 Hz
  pwm.setPWMFreq(50);
  pwm.begin();

}

void loop() {
  myQuadruped.walk();

}
```

Comment: What does pwm.setPWM function does? what are its parameters?Like the first parameter is pin what is 2nd and 3rd

Comment: "setPWM(channel, on, off): This function sets the start (on) and end (off) of the high segment of the PWM pulse on a specific channel.  You specify the 'tick' value between 0..4095 when the signal will turn on, and when it will turn of.  Channel indicates which of the 16 PWM outputs should be updated with the new values."

Comment: Why are your legs different class types? You can have a leg that takes the channels for that leg in the CTOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your leg classes (fRight, fLeft, bRight, bLeft) creates two variables:

```
int channels[2]= {2, 3};
bool started= false;
```

...which creates a different copy which cannot be accessed through the Leg pointer.

You need to change to something like the following to make sure you are setting the values in the base struct, Leg.

```
struct fRight :  Leg
{
    fRight() {
        started = false;
        channels[0] = 0;
        channels[1] = 1;
    }
    virtual void foo() {}
};
```

It's possible you don't even need these individual classes though (depending on what your pure virtual foo() needs to do).  If you were to change Leg to look like:

```
struct Leg
{
    Leg(int channel1, int channel2) :
        started {false}
    {
        channels[0] = channel1;
        channels[1] = channel1;
    }

    int channels[2];
    bool started;
    //virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

... you could just instantiate:

```
Leg* myLegs[4] = { new Leg{0,1}, new Leg{2,3}, new Leg{4,5}, new Leg{6,7} }
```

Comment: I had thought that polymorphism allows the compiler to determine the appropriate variable type during runtime, so that the pointers to Leg will be able to see the member variables "channels" and "started."

Comment: @Skipher the compiler determines absolutely nothing at runtime, because there is no compiler at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have redefined `int channels[2]` in every successor, now you have Leg::channels available via Leg* and LegSuccessors::channels invisible in your use case. Leg::channels not initialiazed, so it filled with garbage values.
To solve the problem, first remove channels declarations in Leg successors. Second, redefine `Leg* myLegs[4]` to `{new fRight{0, 1}, new fLeft{2, 3}, ... and so on};`